# Python Pyinstaller not generating exe file, if console is disabled

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller

I've been stuck on the very last step of creating my program.
I am trying to pack it in to an executable file using pyinstaller, but there is this weird bug  (?), I've come across.

I tried packaging it using
`pyinstaller --icon=64x64.ico --noconsole file.py` 
Which results into build folder, spec file and dist folder, but the dist folder does not contain exe file. If, however, I remove the `--noconsole`  part, everything works fine, though, with the console window in the background when running. The code does not interact with the console at all, and I even tried using it with the console open, to see it if displays anything, and the results were negative.

Any ideas what to look for?

EDIT:
Managed to solve the problem, but further investigating @VictorS's suggestion with pyw extension. Tried running `pyinstaller kalkulators_v2.0.pyw` in CMD , which managed to create all the files in dist folder and also surpress the console

Comment: @Richards are you on Windows?

Comment: @VictorS yes, Sir, running on windows 10

Comment: @Richards If your intention is to use --noconsole to suppress the terminal window on startup, then consider changing the file.py extention to .pyw which in windows will cause this option to be set.

Comment: @VictorS upon you suggestion I tried package it with the command line: `pyinstaller --icon=64x64.ico kalkulators_v2.0.pyw` , but ends up giving the same result as if I used --noconsole.

But your assumption was right, I just want to run the program as it does right now, but to hite the console. But no matter which option I use (-w, --windowed etc.) it gives the same result - missing dist folder contents

Comment: `--windowed` also prevents a console window from being displayed when the application is run. Can you replace `--noconsole` with `--windowed`

Comment: @tidakdiinginkan Tried both of the options, but, unfortunately, it give the same end result with missing exe file

Comment: @Rihards Try. 'pyinstaller --onefile --icon=64x64.ico kalkulators_v2.0.pyw'

Comment: @Richards If that does not work please try: ''pyinstaller --icon=64x64.ico kalkulators_v2.0.pyw'   I believe this should work based on a small test I just performed.

Comment: @Rihards under the dist folder, there should be another folder called whatever your script name is. The executable will be under that.

Comment: I did try both of the options @VictorS , but what ended up happening on the other computer was the exe file destroyed itself after not being able to locate something.

Legorooj, no files at all are created if I use console option. Its completely empty